# gcc 4.6.2 installation on OSX Lion: "g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus'"

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, osx-lion

I downloaded gcc 4.6.2 (with GMP, MPFR, and MPC) and did a build. I could see `g++` executable in `build/gcc` directory.

When I try to use it

```
./g++ test.cpp
```

I get the following error:

`g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory`

1. How to resolve this?
2. How to use the newly built g++ by default?

PS.
I followed these steps to install and I didn't see any error.

```
$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
$ export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.2
$ export CPP=/usr/bin/cpp-4.2
$ export LD=/usr/bin/ld # not /usr/bin/gcc-4.2!!

Clean also your $PATH as much as possible:
$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin
(I don’t know exactly if this is necessary but works fine for me and when you close the Terminal the PATH reverts to its original setting).

1. Download the GCC, GMP, MPFR, and MPC sources. The links are in the original post.
2. Save everything in, say, ~/Downloads (or any directory you prefer).
3. Start the Terminal and run the following commands (change the filenames according to the version you have downloaded):
$ cd # go to your home directory
$ mkdir src ; cd src
$ tar -xzf ~/Downloads/gcc-4.6.1.tar.gz # change the path if you have saved the sources elsewhere!
$ tar -xjf ~/Downloads/gmp-5.0.2.tar.bz2
$ tar -xzf ~/Downloads/mpc-0.9.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf ~/Downloads/mpfr-3.0.1.tar.gz
$ cd gcc-4.6.1
$ ln -s ../gmp-5.0.2 gmp
$ ln -s ../mpc-0.9 mpc
$ ln -s ../mpfr-3.0.1 mpfr

4. Now create a build directory in ~/src but **outside** the gcc source tree, so that it can easily cleaned up to restart everything from scratch:
$ cd ~/src
$ mkdir build ; cd build
$ ../gcc-4.6.1/configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations on getting GCC 4.6.2 on MacOS X 10.7 built - I was not successful (even with the 4.6.1 compiler that I'd built OK).  If I had notes about what went wrong, I'd share war stories with you.

GCC is compiled to be installed in some particular location (`/usr/local` by default, I believe).  When you are running in the build area, you have to redirect it to find its executables in the correct alternative location - there are options to do that.

Run `g++ --help`.  The `-B` option is probably what you need.  My G++ 4.6.1 gives this output:

```
$ g++ -print-search-dirs
install: /usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/
programs: =/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/bin/
libraries: =/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/lib/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/../../../:/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/
$
```

I specified `--prefix=/usr/gcc/v4.6.1` when I ran `configure`.  (Tip: The configured prefix should either not exist when you do the build or the path should not involve any symlinks - because GCC will build the 'real path' into the binary (resolving all symlinks), not the value given on the command line.  This matters if you have any plans to use the code on different machines.)

Comment: The make install does not seem to have touched the existing g++ installation. when I go `print-search-dirs`everything referes to the 4.2.1 one which comes by default. My build is in a local directory called build and I don't know how to proceed. When I tried compiling a sample program using `build/gcc/g++ test.cc`, I got the error as in question.

Comment: If you looked at the commands executed by GCC while it was busy compiling itself, you'd find it used a `-B` option to point it to where its component parts are. You'll need to do the same, or use the installed version which, since you make no mention of prefixes, is probably in `/usr/local` (`/usr/local/bin/g++`). You can arrange to use it in preference to `/usr/bin/g++` by rearranging your PATH so `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin`. (My PATH has `/usr/gcc/v4.6.1/bin` on it ahead of the system directories; it also has my `$HOME/bin` directory and some others in front of the system dirs.)